# computing weight based on distance from centre of ellipse

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I was using a circular image mask before and I was calculating a weight based on the distance from the centre of the circle as follows:

```
import numpy as np
def create_mask(image, radius, center=(0, 0)):
    r, c, d = image.shape
    x, y = np.ogrid[:r, :c]
    distance = np.sqrt((x-center[0])**2 + (y-center[1])**2)
    m = distance < radius
    distance[m] = 1.0 - distance[m]/radius
    array = np.zeros((r, c))
    array[m] = distance[m]
    return array
```

This was basically setting the height weight at the centre and the weight was dropping linearly towards the edges.

Now, I want to do something similar with an ellipse. Again, the ellipse can have very different radii along the two dimensions and I would like the weight to drop linearly with distance as well. However, regardless of the long or the short radii, I would like the weights to decay similarly towards the edges. I am guessing I need to include a weight based on both the radius to achieve this but was unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about linear weights, but you can achieve a continuous array weights from 1 to 0 using (and I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this)

```
ellipse = lambda x0, y0, r_x, r_y: lambda x, y: ((x - x0) / r_x)**2 + ((y - y0) / r_y)**2

def gen_ellipse(el, lower, upper, step):
    coords = np.arange(lower, upper, step)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(coords, coords)
    mask = el(x, y)
    mask[np.where(mask > 1)] = 0
    return 1 - mask
```

For example:

```
> %pylab
> el = ellipse(0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.8)
> mask = gen_ellipse(el, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0025)
> imshow(mask, cmap=get_cmap('Greys'))
```

[image: elliptical mask]

Where black is 1 and white is 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate one thing for me? I parameterise the ellipse using the skimage draw function which takes the x and y center coordinates and the radius along the two dimensions. Could you help me see that equivalency in your code?

Comment: @Luca I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  The ellipse function I have above (now updated by farenorth) can accept x and y offsets, but previously it was just centered at `(0, 0)`, and is parametrized on the two radii of the ellipse.

Comment: I modified the names of the variables, for clarity `(x0, y0)` specify the center of the ellipse, and `(r_x, r_y)` define its radii.

Comment: @Luca I've made the `gen_ellipse` function more efficient and idiomatic, and in the process discovered that my hasty math had the ellipse reflected across `y = x` (I got my x and y coordinates swapped).  The idea is the same, though, it's just a tall ellipse instead of a short ellipse, corresponding to `r_x < r_y`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am trying to adapt this to my needs. I will update my progress tomorrow.

Comment: This indeed works like a charm. Thanks a lot @bheklilr

Comment: There is just one small thing. We have mask[np.where(mask > 1)] = 0
    return 1 - mask. We should store the indexes and set them to 0 after the inversion. Something like: ids = mask > 1 m = 1 - m m[ids] = 0. This ensure that areas outside the mask become 0.